# SQL Exception executeQuery: 17041, Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 3

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

Hi I'm having an specific problem with my code in java comunicating with an oracle server.

I'm doing a call in oracle in order to retrieve a data using an Stored procedure. This is my call.

```
String procedure = "{call " + instnace+ "." + package+ "." + "GetRequestData(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" + "}";
```

This Stored Proecudre receives 2 values, COD_AREA and TELEFONO, and then return 18 Values.

```
try{            
    pstmt.setString(1, RQ.getCOD_AREA());
    pstmt.setString(2, RQ.getTELEFONO());//TELEFONO()               
    pstmt.executeQuery();               
        int o_requestid= (pstmt.getInt(3));
        RP.setO_requestid(String.valueOf(o_requestid));
        RP.setO_requestdate(pstmt.getString(4));
        RP.setO_requesterid(pstmt.getString(5));
        RP.setO_requesterfirstname(pstmt.getString(6));
        RP.setO_requesterlastname(pstmt.getString(7));
        RP.setO_requestercompanyname(pstmt.getString(8));
        RP.setO_requesterclassname(pstmt.getString(9));
        RP.setO_requesteremail(pstmt.getString(10));
        RP.setO_address1(pstmt.getString(11));
        RP.setO_address2(pstmt.getString(12));
        RP.setO_city(pstmt.getString(13));
        RP.setO_state(pstmt.getString(14));
        int o_autoinstall= (pstmt.getInt(15));
        RP.setO_autoinstall(String.valueOf(o_autoinstall));
        RP.setO_plandesired(pstmt.getString(16));
        RP.setO_riskanalisis(pstmt.getString(17));
        RP.setO_status(pstmt.getString(18));
        int n_error= (pstmt.getInt(19));
        RP.setN_error(String.valueOf(n_error));     
        RP.setStr_error(pstmt.getString(20));           
    CerrarConexion(conn);
}
```

The error I'm having is: `SQL Exception executeQuery: 17041, Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 3` Why I'm having this? I searched on stackoverflow and other sites but its related with inserts and updates, but not with Stored Procedures. I appreciate if anyone can help me out with this.

This is my beginConnection method:

```
private OracleCallableStatement beginConnection(String firmaSP) throws SystemException, Exception {

    OracleCallableStatement pstmt = null;
    // Se obtiene la conexion a la BD
    conn = Conexion.getConnection(infoGenerico, 0);
    pstmt = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall(firmaSP);
    return pstmt;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have parameters that are IN, and IN OUT at least.  With a stored procedure that you need to call, you should use a `CallableStatement`, not a `PreparedStatement`, which I'm assuming you're using based on the variable name `pstmt`.  A `CallableStatement` allows you to return values back.

Then for every parameter in which you expect values back (IN OUT and OUT), you must register the out parameter with [the `registerOutParameter` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter-int-int-) before you execute it with `execute()`.

> Registers the OUT parameter in ordinal position parameterIndex to the JDBC type sqlType. All OUT parameters must be registered before a stored procedure is executed.

E.g.:

```
cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.Integer);
```

With Java 8 there is an overload that that takes a `SQLType` instead of an `int` for the type parameter.